# How to extends 2 library classes in android

Tags: java, android, multiple-inheritance

I know that java doesn't support multiple inheritance. So how can i fulfill following requirement.

This is my current class:

```
public class Class1 extends ExpandableListActivity implements ExpandableListView.OnChildClickListener, OnTouchListener, OnItemLongClickListener, OnClickListener, Runnable
{

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
...
}

}
```

Now i also want to extends it using "FragmentActivity" class.

Example:

```
public class Class1 extends ExpandableListActivity, FragmentActivity implements ExpandableListView.OnChildClickListener, OnTouchListener, OnItemLongClickListener, OnClickListener, Runnable
{

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
...
}  

}
```

Comment: I dont think that is possible. You can try to add ExpandableListView as an item in the Fragment Activity's layout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot. You are implementing an activity, so it should be either an ExpandableListActivity or a FragmentActivity, but it cannot be both. Depending on what your actual needs are, you should choose one. But one approach that is possible is to add an ExpandableListView to your FragmentActivity layout.

Comment: If i extend class using FragmentActivity then it throws an error on follwing location in my code....ExpandableListView elv = getExpandableListView();setListAdapter(mAdapter);registerForContextMenu(getExpandableListView());

Comment: I fixed it by extending the activity using "FragmentActivity" class and defining the ExpandableListView in my layout file and it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

we can show ExpandableListView in android XML file.So, use Fragment Activity show ExpandableListView in android XML.

Answer (score 0):

In java a class cannot extent more than one class. But Interface can extends more than one classes.

This is only way to extends more than one class and then use that interface in your class.